# Assign array field within struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

recently i started working on C++ code and i was trying to communicate with an external library which has a struct defined as follows

```
struct StudentsInformation {
    int student_count[10];
    double total_marks[10];
    double section_marks_average;
    double class_marks_average;
};
```

I was trying to create a object for this struct as follows in a separate class

```
int count[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
double marks[10] = {10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0};

StudentsInformation stuInfo = { count, marks, 68.8, 56.7 };
```

Compiling this provides following error

> Cannot initialize an array element of type 'int' with an lvalue of
> type 'int [10]'

not sure what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: `int count[11]` and `int student_count[10];` doesn't match. And what is `CalLoad` and how is it related to the shown `StudentsInformation ` structure? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Then copy-paste the full and complete build output from building that examplke.

Comment: Lastly, you can neither assign to an array (the full array) nor initialize it using another array. You need to copy from the source array to the destination array. Or use some other data-type which supports assignment (like `std::array`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's the answer to the question. Please put it in the answer section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should compile fine, in either/both C and/or C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct StudentsInformation {
    int student_count[10];
    double total_marks[10];
    double section_marks_average;
    double class_marks_average;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  struct StudentsInformation si = {
    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
    {10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0},
    68.8, 56.7
  };

  return 0;
}
```

The key part of the error message is "cannot convert an lvalue":

> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category
>
> *lvalue*:
>
> the name of a variable, a function, a template parameter object (since
> C++20), or a data member, regardless of type, such as std::cin or
> std::endl. Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the
> expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression;

Comment: @Rajesh - does this answer your question?  You *can* initialize an array within a struct when you declare it ... but cannot do so by using the name of another, different array variable.